# Any tetrahedral geometry theorems of methane bonding angles?

Tags: vector-spaces

For my 12 grade folio task I need to find alternate ways of finding the bonding angles in a methane molecule (regular tetrahedron). I have already done it through vector methods, co-ordinate geometry and triangle theorems.

I was wondering if anyone knows of, or can explain to me, any advanced maths that can find the bonding angle or theorems that can be used to deduce it.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Apply [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) to an equilateral geodesic triangle on the unit  sphere with edge length $\theta$ (the angle you seek) with angle $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, you get

$$\cos\theta = \cos\theta^2 + \sin\theta^2 \cos\frac{2\pi}{3}
\iff 3\cos\theta^2 - 2\cos\theta - 1 = (3\cos\theta + 1)(\cos\theta - 1) = 0$$
Since $\theta \ne 0$, this leads to $\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac13\right)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I didn't expect anyone to answer this soon. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a regular tetrahedron with each edge $a$ & having vertices A, B, C, D & center O.  $$AB=BC=AC=AD=BD=CD=a$$

Then the radius of the spherical surface passing through all 4 identical vertices of regular tetrahedron is given (see [table](https://www.academia.edu/9780115/Table_for_the_important_parameters_dimensions_for_construction_of_all_five_platonic_solids_calculated_by_using_HCRs_generalized_formula_for_regular_polyhedrons) or [derivation](https://www.academia.edu/9727820/HCRs_Formula_for_Regular_n-Polyhedron_Mathematical_analysis_of_regular_n-polyhedrons_all_five_platonic_solids_)) by the formula $$OA=OB=OC=OD=\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Now, consider any isosceles triangle say $\triangle OAB$ in which we have $$OA=OB=\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}, \ \ AB=a$$ Now, applying Cosine rule in $\triangle OAB$ to find $\angle AOB$ as follows $$cos \angle AOB=\frac{(OA)^2+(OB)^2-(AB)^2}{2(OA)(OB)}$$ Now, setting the corresponding values we get $$\cos \angle AOB=\frac{\left(\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^2-a^2}{2\left(\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}$$ $$=\frac{\frac{3a^2}{4}-a^2}{\frac{3a^2}{4}}=\frac{-\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}}$$ $$=-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\angle AOB=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)=\pi-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{Methane bonding angle }=\color{blue}{\pi-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\approx 109.47^\circ}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with algebra.

The faces of a a tetrahedral are equilateral triangles.

Suppose 3 vertices of the tetrahedral are $(0,0,0),(1,0,0), (1/2, \sqrt{3}/2,0)$

Where is the 4th point? Let its coordinates be $(x,y,z)$.

Then:

$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

$(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2=1$

$(x-1/2)^2+(y-\sqrt{3}/2)^2+z^2=1$

Subtracting the second equation from the first, you find $2x-1=0\implies x=1/2$

So:

$y^2+z^2=3/4$

$(y-\sqrt{3}/2)^2+z^2=1$

Subtract the second from the first here you get:

$y\sqrt{3}-3/4=-1/4\implies y=1/2\sqrt{3}\implies z=\pm \sqrt{2/3}$

Now find the center of mass of the system by adding up all the coordinate and dividing by 4.

$C=(1/2, 1/\sqrt{12}, \sqrt{1/24})$

The distance of $C$ from the origin is $1/4+1/12+1/24=3/8=d^2\implies d=\sqrt{3/8}$

By the cosine rule $1=2(3/8)-2(3/8)\cos \theta=(3/2)\sin^2 \theta/2$

$\theta= 2\arcsin(\sqrt{2/3})\implies \theta = 109.47^\circ $